# In as many different ways, the photographer can do the ranking

Tags: combinatorics

Five pair of lovers decide to take a photo together. Photography selects their order to obtain the most beautiful pictures. In as many different ways, the photographer can do the ranking, if any

$a)$ if everyone will be in a row and the couple members are next to each other

$b)$ if they will be organized in two rows so that the boys are in one row and the girls in the other

Comment: What does "if the boys are to be organized in two rows and in one row the girls become the other" mean?

Comment: sorry, i correct

Comment: why negative vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) First arrange a couples that is $5!$ and then for each couple you have 2 possibilites so the answer is $$5!\cdot 2^5$$

b) In this case it is just $5! \cdot 5!$.

Comment: please can you detail, using any formula how, since i don't understand the example at all

Comment: thanky very much sir

Comment: group the $n$ "couples" as separate objects there are $n!$ ordering of the $n$ objects, there are then $m!$ ways to order within each object containing $m$ sub-objects so we have $n!(m!)^n$ ways.

Comment: You took the word out of my mouth @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: In how many ways can 10 different books be distributed to 3 students so that each student get minimum two book and maximum four book, can you help me for this question, pleaseeee

Comment: Post it as another question.

Comment: ask as a separate question ...

Comment: I post this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533132/how-many-different-ways-the-teacher-can-distribute-the-books

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533132/how-many-different-ways-the-teacher-can-distribute-the-books  @betmen12 you need to show your attempts ...

Comment: Huh -7 .................

Comment: I didnt now why the negative vote, @ Aqua , help me please

Comment: Well, people generally don't want to do the others job...

Comment: what that means

Comment: mY ANSWERS FOR THIS EXAMPLE IS 2565, but i didnt know that is corect

Comment: C(10,4)+C(10,2)=2565, or else, help me